# Can IF statement simplify my report?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got this report in which I need figure out the number of IDs that are within the City.

```
 
 |A|       |B|         |C|         |D|              |E|
 |ID|    |SECTOR|    |TYPE|    |Measured Area|    |In the city|
 |1|      |2|         |CC|        |1844|           |YES|
 |1|      |2|         |A|         |558|            |YES|
 |2|      |2|         |CC|        |1844|           |NO|
 |2|      |2|         |A|         |558|            |YES|
 |2|      |2|         |CC|        |1844|           |YES|
 |3|      |2|         |A|         |558|            |NO|
```

To do so, right now I'm filtering the report so that I can see only the ID's that are within the city, copy it to a new excel sheet, and then I'm counting the ID's with this: `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0,1))`.

I understand that an IF statement goes like this `IF(logical_test,value_is_true,value_is_false])`. Logical Test is the operation I'm doing. Value is true is what I will get if the operation is true, and value is false is what I get when the operation is false.

In my code `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0,1))` , `1` is the number I'm adding if the logical test is true, so I was thinking about changing `1` with an `IF` statement to check for the ID that I'm suppose to add `1`. It would check if its within the city or not, but sadly I wasn't able to make that if statement.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I changed the word "Rapport" to "report" because I believe that was the word you were looking for. If I am incorrect, can you clarify what "Rapport" is?

Comment: Have you considered using a countif statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(E2:E7="YES",1/COUNTIFS(A2:A7,A2:A7,E2:E7,"YES")))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]